# How to use UISplitViewController in tvml (tvOS)

Tags: ios, tvos, tvml, tvjs

I'm fairly new to TVML programming and I'm trying to add splitview as my rootviewcontroller in a tvOS app which is using tvml and tvjs. The closest thing I can find is **catalogTemplate** but it doesn't have the properties to hide/show split view. I want to use UISplitviewcontroller as my root and have other child views loaded on selection. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/interface-elements/split-views/

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to implement it yourself and make it available through an extended interface creator. See [TVInterfaceCreating](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvmlkit/tvinterfacecreating). You can also find a (very) small example in the [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TVMLKitJS/Conceptual/TVMLProgrammingGuide/TVMLKitArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016718-CH21-SW1).